# How to get Jelly Bean Camera to use external SD card?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, camera, external-sd

I just purchased a 32 GB SD card for use with my Galaxy S3 which is running a 4.2.1 rom. Certain apps like Titanium Backup I was able to switch to start using the SD card just fine, but I can't for the life of me find a setting anywhere for the camera to start storing videos/photos there. Is this possible?

I've googled lots, but all I can find is directions for older versions of Android, which aren't applicable to my setup.

Comment: Have you checked the settings in the camera app? In several versions, it has a "storage" option where you can define that.

Comment: Unfortunately on this version of Android, the only things in the settings menu are picture/video quality options depending on the mode I'm in. Hitting the actual Android settings button while in the application doesn't bring up any menu at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1. Go into Camera as if you were taking a picture
2. Go into Settings (gear) on top left
3. Scroll down to Storage
4. Change to Memory Card

Comment: The poster already commented that they lack this particular setting.

Comment: Honestly this option wasn't there for the longest time, and I've been running 4.2.2 for a while. It must have been a bug with the rom I was using, it's there now and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't found the setting for this, I stumbled upon it tonight on my 4.2.1 phone. I'd previously set it without realising (only just made the move over to Android) and after removing my SD card the other day, I found after I re-inserted it into the phone it would only save to the internal flash memory... I couldn't for the life of me figure out what I'd done!

Finally figured it out:-

Go to the main Android system settings menu and select Storage. The very top option is to select the default write disk - set this to SD card and back out of the menus.

Job done. :)

Cheers,

Nick

Comment: So weird, I don't have that option. Can you post a screenshot? I've still got about 20GB sitting around doing nothing  :(

Here's the top of my storage screen https://www.dropbox.com/s/agxhshsxzdb9cqf/2013-05-07%2000.11.37.png

Answer (score 0):

Long press the screen when in camera, this will popup a menu, within there u can select settings, and change storage to sdcard. You can also press the flashlight button on the right to get that menu.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Default Write Disk from Phone storage to SD card.
Android Setting->Storage->Change the Default Write Disk